# FAB blocked by ViewPager

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

My floating action bar is blocked by viewpager that I have in the same page.

I would like to add FAB to the intent himselfs and not to the fragment that inside the viewpager, so I've added to my main layout file this code:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/pluscircle" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#2e9100"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

But for some reason my FAB is appearing below the tablayout and above viewPager like this: [image: FAB error]

How can I fix the FAB location so he wont be blocked by viewPager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `FrameLayout` with `layout_gravity` also apply `android:clickable="true"` to the root layout.

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#2e9100"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

Well i'm not sure what i'm gonna answer will be your solution coz honestly i didn't get your question, use FrameLayout for views in different levels (here, your FAB should be on in the topmost FrameLayout).
Good luck!

Comment: you should post this comment